# When calling a servlet from a class my sessions are always null

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

i need to check if a session exist on my jsp site. I created a servlet that checks it inside its `doPost()` and doGet() methods.

Both If i call it from url (url/Servlet) and after submitting a page   `<form action="Servlet" method="post">` it works.

Now I need to call the doPost() or doGet() methods from a class. Reading some posts on this forum i got this code:

```
   Sessione p = new Sessione(); //sessione is the servlet name
   URL urlServlet = null;

   urlServlet = new URL("url/Servlet");
   HttpURLConnection servletConnection = (HttpURLConnection) urlServlet.openConnection();
   servletConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
   servletConnection.setDoOutput(true);

   ObjectOutputStream objOut = new ObjectOutputStream(servletConnection.getOutputStream());
   objOut.writeObject(p);
   objOut.flush();
   objOut.close();
   InputStream response = servletConnection.getInputStream();
```

The problem is that if i call that servlet from a class i always get that my sessions are null, even when they arent.

this is the doPost() method of my servlet

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();     
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);     
        out.println(session.getAttribute("loggato"));

    }
```

Comment: I edited the tile, i made a mistake while typing :)

Comment: I don't see you submit a session id, how is your servlet meant to know which session you want to check? Btw, what's the use case for this? Maybe there's an easier/more elegant/more secure way of achieving your goal.

Comment: my goal is to check in every page/servlet of my site is a sessione exists. If it exists the user can sees pages, otherwise he has to login. For this reason i created a class, to call in avery page/servòet, that calls a servlet that checks my sessione

Comment: Maybe this could help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14243455/check-for-valid-session-isrequestedsessionidvalid-vs-getsessionfalse - alternatively use a servlet filter (result of a quick tutorial search: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/http-session-handling-tutorial-using-servlet-filters-session-error-filter-servlet-filter/)

Comment: Instead of checking this in every page you could implement a filter which does this for you.

Comment: Ok, I just started studying the filters. Thanks everybody for the advices.